# function returning from stream int value (c++)

Tags: c++, function, inputstream

I'd like to use in my programme something like that:

```
object = constructor(std::cin.get(), std::cin.get());
```

but in this case it doesn't work, becouse cin.get() convert numbers coming from stream to ASCII code and the second problem is that cin.get() leaves NULL in entrance. Is it any function that will meet my requirements? I know that I can use something like this instead:

```
int x, y;
std::cin >> x >> y;
object=constructor(x,y);
```

but i'd like to use a solution like I showed you before.

constructor prototype is:

```
constructor(int, int);
```

Comment: Don't, function argument evaluation order is not always left to right.

Comment: Can't you make another constructor overload which takes a stream as argument and extracts the values?

Comment: You could also overload the stream operator and do something like `Object foo; cin >> foo;`

Comment: `object=constructor(x,y);` Huh? I realise that this is pseudo-code, but at _best_ you're misunderstanding how functional type case notation works (it's not a constructor call); at worst you're getting object declaration wrong.

Comment: How do you want to handle cases where `std::cin.get()` fails?